# Issue getting ember to interact with rails, 'no adapter' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-data

I'm getting an error while trying to get ember to `findAll()' within the store.

The error is `Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: You tried to load all records but you have no adapter (for team)`

My relevant files are as such:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

**/router.js.coffee**

```
 App.Router.map ()->   
   @resource('teams')
```

**/store.js.coffee**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  # Override the default adapter with the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` which
  # is built to work nicely with the ActiveModel::Serializers gem.
  adapter: '_ams'
```

**/routes/teams_route.js.coffee**

```
App.TeamsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
  @store.findAll('team')
```

**/templates/teams.hbs**

```
<h1>Teams</h1>

  <ul class="list-group">

    {{#each model}}


   {{#link-to 'team' this class="list-group-item"}}
     {{team_name}}
   {{/link-to}}

    {{/each}}


 </ul>
```

**JSON at /teams.json**

```
{"teams":[{"id":20,"team_name":"Greg's Team","user_id":9},{"id":21,"team_name":"Joe's Team","user_id":10}]}
```

I can't seem to find where im going wrong, hoping that maybe a fresh pair of eyes can pick it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `_ams` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by upgrading from ember-data `v0.14` to `v1.00 Beta.7`

I'm still experiencing some issues with the code, however this, and switching the adapter to  `-active-model` from the deprecated `_ams` resolved the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
App.TeamsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
  @store.findAll('team')
```

With

```
App.TeamsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
  @store.findAll('teams')
```

**Note:** `teams` plural

Comment: Thanks Kirti, but that returns `Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: You tried to load all records but you have no adapter (for teams)`

Comment: Instead of _ams adapter, try with `DS.RESTAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is to simply extend the ActiveModelAdapter as follows:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend()
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend()
```

Ember will now automatically use your `ApplicationAdapter`.

More info at http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-other-adapters/.

Comment: I actually tinkered with this a little bit also, however it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined` for `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend()`.